# How can C++ applications access a remote MySQL database without making MySQL server accept remote connections?

Tags: c++, database, client

I'm looking for an effective approach for this problem:

Server:

- Webinterface, User can use forms.
- The Data entered in the forms is getting saved in a database.

Several clients:

- A client program written in c++ can access database.

When I use a normal MySQL DB I would have to open the whole MySQLServer to accept remote connections, which I would like to avoid.

I found several MySQL APIs, but no alternative for my problem. 
An 'webdatabase <-> remote c++ client' solution.

Will I have to write my own server which will parse the DB info to the client? :/

Hope there is an easier solution!

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is write an API that runs on the same webinterface to which you can programatically talk. You can look at SOAP for example, or a REST based service, or simply JSON.

This will allow your C++ client to "connect" to the database on the server side through a controlled channel so that you are not opening up MySQL to access from the outside.